Access Display Custom Color Settings of AMD driver via script
unfortunately "Gamma Panel" stopped working on my PC lately (settings have no effect). But i noticed, that my AMD driver can modify the PC gamma settings aswell. I would like to create shortcuts to switch my gamma with a single button-press.
Does someone know if AMD offers an API or is there an CLI to do so? The language does not really matter to me, i would also be willing to write a small GUI for it.

